# Saving a result after calling a function on an array into another array, Javascript, multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm writing some functions to operate on a multi-dimensional array and can't figure out how to save the result to use it in a different place of my programm (the arrays in which the result within one function is being saved are local and not global).

Let's say, there is an array of objects:

```
    const objects = [
    ['objectname', objectAge, anotherValue],
    ['objectname2', objectAge2, anotherValue2],
    ['objectname3', objectAge3, anotherValue3]
];
```

Then I can define a function and call it (an array will be printed to a console)

```js
const objects = [
  ['objectname', objectAge, anotherValue],
  ['objectname2', objectAge2, anotherValue2],
  ['objectname3', objectAge3, anotherValue3]
];

function functionName(array) {
  let objectNames = array.map(function(object) {
    return object[0];
  });

  console.log(objectNames);
}
functionName(objects);

let currentTime = new Date()

let YYYY = (new Date()).getFullYear()

function functionAge(object) {

let ageArray = object.map(function(year) {
let age = YYYY - year[1];
return age;
})
console.log(ageArray);
}

functionAge(objects);

let array1 = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'],
array2 = [12,11,16],
result =[];

for (let i=0; i< array1.length;i++) {
result.push([array1[i],array2[i]]);
}
console.log(result);


let array3 = functionName(objects);
let array4 = functionAge(objects),
result2 =[];

for (let i=0; i< array3.length;i++) {
result.push([array3[i],array4[i]]);
}
console.log(result2);
```

But when I want to use the returned array and do something else with it in, let's say, another function, I'm trying to save the "result" (what I believe is an array) into a new array or access it directly by

```
let savedResult = functionName(objects);
```

or

```
let savedResult = objects.functionName();
```

and it doesn't work, I either get something like an array of undefined or just an error in my console saying that savedResult.length is impossible to call.

Could someone please give me a hint, where I can check that JavaScript option to reuse the results of a function applied to an array?

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The **return object[0]** gives value to the **objectNames** variable. But the **functionName** function does not return with it. So it returns with 'undefined'.

```
function functionName(array) {
    return array.map(function(object) {
        return object[0];
    })
}
functionName(objects);
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Your function functionName()  is a void function which is not return anything so the result is undefined use return statement to return somthing for the function like the code below

```
function functionName(array) {
  let objectNames = array.map(function(object) {
    return object[0];
  });
  return objectNames
}
```